# How can I read a csv file from current working directory?

Tags: python

I want to define a function to read a csv file from my Desktop without directly typing the specific directory. Here is my old code:

```
def CSV(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\Myfile.csv')
```

But if someone else wants to read the file, they have to type the directory again. I firstly used the code in the following:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

And I got the directory: C:\Users\Aaron.
So how can I make the function read the csv file from this current directory?
I tried the following code:

```
    def CSV(filename):
        return pd.read_csv(os.path.join(Desktop, 'Myfile.csv'))
    print(CSV('Myfile.csv'))
```

But it says Undefined name 'Desktop'.

Comment: 'Desktop' is what you want I guess, in your last line. Desktop as a variable is not defined, that's why it says Undeffined name ('Desktop' is a string, Desktop is a variable).

Answer (score 1):

Desktop is not a variable its a string so you have to pass it in a single quotes:

```
def CSV(filename):
    filename +='.csv'     #if filename not containing extension
    return pd.read_csv(os.path.join('Desktop',filename))
```

If your want to read the file from current working directory you should try something like this:

```
def read_csv_file(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Note: You are passing filename as a parameter to this function and probably you are opening this file, so remember if you are accessing a variable or a parameter it must be without quotes.